# ExoPlayer (v2.6.1) - manually painting closed captions?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I'm trying to fix an issue with our video player where Roll-On captions are causing a continuous stutter in the playback of HSL streams. The issue does not happen with other types of CC's like Paint-On.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to update to a newer version of exoplayer (like Media3) due to the tight coupling of out code.

What I've tried is basically to buffer the captions and then manually painting them on using `setCues()` but they just end up getting overwritten by the automatic captions from the player stream.

here is the relevant code:

### Player ViewModel

```kotlin
private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main)

// LiveData for closed captions
private val _closedCaptionsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Cue>>()
val closedCaptionsLiveData: LiveData<List<Cue>> = _closedCaptionsLiveData

// Buffer for storing closed captions
private val captionBuffer: MutableList<Cue> = mutableListOf()

// Coroutine timer for updating LiveData
private var updateTimer: Job? = null

init {
    startCaptionUpdateTimer()
}

private fun startCaptionUpdateTimer() {
    updateTimer = viewModelScope.launch {
        while (isActive) {
            delay(1500) // Adjust the interval as needed
            _closedCaptionsLiveData.postValue(ArrayList(captionBuffer))
            captionBuffer.clear()
        }
    }
}


fun setLiveTvCcRenderer(enableCC: Boolean) {
    trackGroupArray?.let {
        when (enableCC) {
            true -> {
                LogManager.d(TAG, "Enabling ClosedCaption")
                trackSelector.setRendererDisabled(indexOfTextRenderer, false)
                selectionOverride = SelectionOverride(fixedFactory, ccGroupIndex, ccTrackIndex)
                trackSelector.setSelectionOverride(
                    indexOfTextRenderer,
                    trackGroupArray,
                    selectionOverride
                )
            }

            false -> {
                LogManager.d(TAG, "Disabling ClosedCaption")
                trackSelector.setRendererDisabled(indexOfTextRenderer, true)
                trackSelector.clearSelectionOverride(indexOfTextRenderer, trackGroupArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Player Activity

```kotlin
// Observe LiveData for closed caption updates
liveTvPlayerViewModel.closedCaptionsLiveData.observe(this) { cues ->
    exo_subtitles.setCues(cues)
}

/**
 *  Consumer subscription of the playerStateStream.
 */
private fun setupPlayerStateConsumer() {
    val bufferingScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    var bufferingJob: Job? = null
    var consecutiveBufferRetryCount = 0
    liveTvPlayerEventListener.playerStateStream
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { playerState ->
            // reset the job whenever the state changes
            bufferingJob?.cancel()
            when (playerState) {
                is LiveTvPlayerEvent.State.Playing -> {
                    consecutiveBufferRetryCount = 0
                    if (liveTvPlayerViewModel.isPreparing) {
                        liveTvPlayerViewModel.ccRendererPrepare()
                        exo_subtitles.setApplyEmbeddedStyles(false)
                        exo_subtitles.alpha = CC_TRANSPARENCY
                        if (previousCCEnabledStatus) {
                            enableDiableClosedCaption(true)
                        }
                        liveTvPlayerViewModel.isPreparing = false
                    }
                    // change text of channel unavailable to text of channel
                    playerControlsWrapper.channelName.text =
                        channelController.currentChannel?.title?.getLocalized(this)
                            ?: ""
                    // throw up player view; hide channel unavailable & loading views
                    loadingOverlayWrapper.visibility = View.GONE
                    playerControlsWrapper.channelUnavailable.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    playerControlsWrapper.channelUnavailable.invalidate()
                    // show player view
                    videoPlayerView.playerView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    liveTvPlayerEventListener.loadedBefore = true
                    playlistStuckDisposable.clear()
                }
                is LiveTvPlayerEvent.State.Ended -> {
                    liveTvPlayerViewModel.exoPlayer.seekToDefaultPosition()
                    liveTvPlayerViewModel.exoPlayer.prepare(liveTvPlayerViewModel.mediaSource)
                }
                is LiveTvPlayerEvent.State.Buffering -> {
                    // check if we've tried twice consecutively without success.
                    if (consecutiveBufferRetryCount < 2) {
                        // a new job to retry the channel after 10 seconds of continuous buffer.
                        bufferingJob = bufferingScope.launch {
                            if (consecutiveBufferRetryCount > 0) {
                                delay(MAX_BUFFERING_DURATION_2ND_TRY)
                            } else {
                                delay(MAX_BUFFERING_DURATION)
                                if (isActive) {
                                    consecutiveBufferRetryCount++
                                    playCurrentChannel()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        LogManager.d(TAG, "MAX consecutiveBufferRetryCount reached.")
                        consecutiveBufferRetryCount = 0
                        stopExoPlayer()
                        retryExoPlayer()
                    }
                }
                else -> Unit // TODO other LiveTvPlayerEvents
            }
        }.addTo(startStopDisposable)
}
```

If I just call `trackSelector.setRendererDisabled(indexOfTextRenderer, true)` it just completely disables the rendering of the captions so I'm not sure what to do :/